Steam Executable and Install File Location - Fatal Error / No Executable
Can someone please explain what to input into the Steam Developer Dashboard when trying to get a game to launch after Downloading the build as a developer in the text box where the "General Installation" tab leads you and asks for a launch option that says to put in your executable path? and it also asks for an installation folder.
I believe this is what I am not doing correctly.
My problem is that I can't get my Unreal Engine 5 game to launch from Steam as a developer.
I tried different names for each text box, different executable packages, different methods of upload and I did get it to work with HTTP upload but this is cmdlet upload through Unreal Engine.
